# python web-client multipile set-cookie header, get raw set-cookie header

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests, httplib, urllib3

i am using python-requests on python 2.7,
i am trying to authenticate against a web-server that returns multiple set-cookie headers in the response.
python-requests keeps only one of those cookies.

i couldn't find a python 'http' client that either handles this problem correctly,
or allows access to the raw header with the 'set-cookie' statements in order to manually deal with the problem.

i found a few statements in the internet that claim that this problem was solved in python3, however no further details or examples were provided.

would appreciate any assistance.

thanks

Comment: As far as I know, Requests actually keeps all the cookies, but merges them into one Cookie line. Could you show a code example and the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the Set-Cookie-Header with requests.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://localhost:5000")  
# a flask application there sets two cookies 'first' and 'second'

r.cookies.keys()
# returns ['first', 'second']

r.headers['Set-Cookie']
# returns 'first=4; Path=/, second=42; Path=/'
```

Please show some code of what you did to see why it didn't work for you.

Comment: i checked your code example against https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail and both cookies were kept. i guess that my problem lies elsewhere and that i still have some work to do. thanks